# What is the name of this array transformation?

Tags: algorithms, array

Start with an array of arrays; in this case, they are different lengths in order to demonstrate the technique, but they do not have to be.

```
[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7], [8,9,10], [11,12,13,14,15]]
```

At the other end of the transformation, you have an array of arrays where the first array contains the first element from each of the original arrays, the second array contains the second element from each of the original arrays, and so on.

```
[[1,5,8,11], [2,6,9,12], [3,7,10,13], [4,14], [15]]
```

Is there a mathematical or CS term for this operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called [transposing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) except for the deal with the flaggedness of the arrays

> In linear algebra, the transpose of a matrix A is another matrix A<sup>T</sup>... created by any one of the following equivalent actions:
>
> - reflect A over its main diagonal (which runs from top-left to bottom-right) to obtain A<sup>T</sup>
> - write the rows of A as the columns of A<sup>T</sup>
> - write the columns of A as the rows of A<sup>T</sup>
>
> [image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/Matrix_transpose.gif/200px-Matrix_transpose.gif]

Comment: I feel like I should have recalled this from a math class, but alas, that was some time ago. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean "raggedness"?